# phpDocumentor: document only classes

Tags: php, documentation, document, phpdoc

I'm trying to learn about phpDocumentor. I usually put a classe per file. Am I forced to document file and classes? I want to document just classes (Why should i document files?) but i receive warnings...

```
WARNING in comment.class.php on line 8: DocBlock would be page-level, but precedes class "Comment", use another DocBlock to document the file
```

I've read http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to document the file, it's just a warning.  If you don't put a file-level doc, then there will be no information on the phpdoc "files" list, even though there will be some for the "class" list.

Comment: Is there no way to **suppress** these warnings?

Comment: @NatIsGleek why do you need to suppress them?  When you run the php documentor script you can route error output to `/dev/null`

Comment: phpDocumentor 2.x may add the ability to suppress warnings like this in the future.